Why are these Partial Residual Plots similar despite having different y-axis (partial residual range vs. component + residual)
I am working to produce some partial residual plots to better communicates the effects associated with each independent variable in a multiple regression model. I am using two methods to plot these values and comparing them. One is crPlot and the other is effects() then plotting that object. I'm trying both because crPlots gets me the correct output but the function is miserable to adjust the aesthetic of the plots to make them publication friendly. I was looking for an alternative and found effects(). The code and plots for both are below and the first one is the crPlot. My question is why are both sets of plots for frontal surface area similar despite the y-axis being different and why is the head count plot so different (scaling???)? crPlots the component+residuals and effects plots the "partial residual range". I'm not entirely sure what either of these means. I'd like to use effects() since I can combine it with plot and ggplot to generate visuals but would prefer that it present y-axis that crPlots uses as my understanding is those are the actual residual values. Thank you for your time.
eff1 <- effects::Effect(c("TotalHeadFrontalSA"), m2, partial.residuals = TRUE)
eff2 <- effects::Effect(c("TotalBackFrontalSA"), m2, partial.residuals = TRUE)
eff3 <- effects::Effect(c("HeadCount"), m2, partial.residuals = TRUE)

crPlots(m2, col="black", col.lines=c("black", "red"), main = "Partial Residuals - Drag Coefficient")

plot(eff1)
plot(eff2)
plot(eff3)





